# How to turn off global features in zen carts options_name_manager.php

Tags: php, zen-cart

I have been looking through code and forums for hours. Does any one know how to make it so that by default the Global features drop down is set to off on the options_name_manager file so that the global features are hidden. I have a customer who doesn't need to see those options and so I want to hide it.

I have done some extensive googling and come up blank. Any help is appreciated. I have even tried hard coding the variable which changes the drop down but doesn't hide the section that it needs to!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admin/options_name_manager.php on line 13 in 1.3.9 (right above where the $_GET['action'] is done) do this:

```
  $_SESSION['option_names_values_copier'] = 0;
```

-- updated based on changed requirements

If you want to default it to off but retain the ability to change it, do something more like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['option_names_values_copier'])) { 
   $_SESSION['option_names_values_copier'] = 0;
}
```

Then the setting will only be made if it isn't already set.

Comment: HI i will try this later, will this still allow me to change it with the drop down? (at the moment i put a horrid hack in to make a later if statement always true in order to always hide it as this is preferable to showing it for my customers)

Comment: If you want to change it via the dropdown, change it via the dropdown!  You said you wanted to turn it off.

Comment: No sorry I didn't explain v.well. If i set this it will default to hidden, but i can still show the section if i change the drop down value. Is that right? Sorry for pestering.

Comment: If you logout and log back in, this works correctly.  If you're determined to do it differently, then add a check for admin id, and for the customer's id, set the flag to false every time (like my first solution) and for your id, don't do anything.